# How to convert date into day of the week in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I have a column of dates and I was wondering how I could add another column to show the day of the week?

[image: Screenshot of data]

Comment: `EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM ActivityDay)`

Answer (score 2):

see below example

```
select 
  extract(dayofweek from date('2022-03-02')) as dayofweek_as_number,
  format_date('%a', date('2022-03-02')) as dayofweek_abbreviated,
  format_date('%A', date('2022-03-02')) as dayofweek_fullname
```

with output

[image]